# Editing the original post to include questions

Tags: discussion

I had posted the following question  earlier  :

https://superuser.com/questions/1288633/some-basic-things-like-drive

The answer here by user "sawdust" was quite informative . But I wanted to know few more things , was curious to know about things mentioned answers . 
So , I edited my original post to include some more questions that I got . These new questions are under the P.S. label .

Honestly I am quite eager to know the answers to the new questions so I am worried if what I did is a bad practice and instead of letting these post grow bigger I should have posted them under a new post . So was that a bad practice ? Or because of my low level of knowledge I posted some vague questions ?

Comment: The target scope of a question is something that can be well answered in a limited number of paragraphs. Sometimes it takes more. But if you are asking many questions in one and it takes a small book to answer them all, it's too broad for a single question. The site is designed around specific, bite-sized questions that someone has after doing the background research.  It is not intended for general learning on a subject.  In the question's current form, it's likely to be closed as too broad. However, since sawdust has already answered the extended version, you should not change the scope now.

Answer (score 5):

Editing an already-answered question in a way that significantly expands it is not good practice on Stack Exchange sites.

We're not a forum, but instead a Q&A site, meaning you want to post questions that are as narrowly-scoped as possible. Unlike a forum, once a question has received an answer, the post's scope needs to remain largely unchanged. Otherwise the answers may be invalidated by the "new" version of the question. Instead, make new question posts as necessary and link to your original question to provide context.

If you have a minor clarifying question you wish to ask one of the answerers, a comment below their answer is acceptable. But avoid addressing new material or engaging in lengthy conversation in comments.